# How to Properly Escape Nested Special Characters

Tags: c, string

I need to save below example sentences as a file called `demo.sh`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash   
xmessage This is "first sentence"
xmessage This is 'second sentence'
xmessage This is {third sentence}
```

The code I use in C is below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    system("sudo bash -c 'printf \"#!/usr/bin/env bash\n\" > /usr/share/applications/demo.sh'");
    return 0;
}
```

I can write the first sentence of the above 4 sentences OK into the file. But the other sentences contain special characters like `single quotes`, `double quotes` and `line ending character`. And this gets very difficult to escape because `sudo` command needs to have two nested section which I tried to wrap by `'` and `"` separately.

How can I escape the sentences and write out to the file? It would be great to have some function because actually the file is more than 4 sentences and have many special characters.

As a note, I know I could use I/O functions of C, I want to write the file by a single `system` command which use `sudo`, `printf` and `one line string`.

Comment: Using the `system` is effectively the same as entering those commands in a terminal, any reason for not doing it that way?

Comment: During testing program could not write to `/usr/share/applications/` location because it belongs to `root`. I saw using `sudo bash -c` way is working in Terminal. So I wanted to port the Terminal way into C program. For simple sentences it went great but whenever the sentence contained special characters, it got terribly complex.

Comment: This is not porting it to C, this is merely executing the same bash commands through a C program

Comment: I may have used wrong terminology but you are right. I am writing a file by Terminal command in C.

Answer (score 0):

I dont thing that its the best way, but you can use one char[] variable for system command and sprintf() function to split and write command in this variable

here is an example

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char command[128];

    /* Generate string */
    sprintf(command, "sudo bash -c %s %s bash\n > /usr/share/applications/demo.sh'", 
        "'printf", "#!/usr/bin/env");

    system(command);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I modified your code but whenever I go to second line, it looks horrible. I had to use 3 backslashes for the second sentence double quote escaping. `sprintf(command, "sudo bash -c %s %s > /usr/share/applications/demo.sh'",
        "'printf", "\"#!/usr/bin/env\\nxmessage This is \\\"first sentence\\\"\"");`

Comment: I am not sure why it is needed 3 backslashes.